# How to refer to source file related line numbers in Qt5 code editor?

Tags: qt, editor, qt5, highlight

It is a replacement of the migrated question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36681197/qt5-code-editor-sreen-or-source-line-numbering

I want to highlight a source line using the function below. Basically it works, but when I have a long comment line and the line wraps, the highlighted area is shifted to a wrong line. Reformatting the window size, it works OK, so I guess that the line number refers to the screen line number, rather than the source line number of the document. Is there any option which fixes this difference?

```
void CodeEditor::setCursorToLine(unsigned int lineno)
{
  QTextBlock text_block = document()->findBlockByLineNumber(lineno-1);
  QTextCursor text_cursor = textCursor ();
  text_cursor.setPosition(text_block.position());
  setFocus();
  text_cursor.select(QTextCursor::BlockUnderCursor);
  setTextCursor(text_cursor);
}
```

Comment: what’s “Qt5 code editor”? QtCreator, or your own code?

Comment: Please see http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-widgets-codeeditor-example.html